# Stuck while proving an inequality by induction in another way

Tags: inequality, induction

There is an inequality
$$
1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\geq\sqrt{n}
$$
that could be proved by induction adding $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ term to both sides of the inequality. I tried to prove it in another way by induction multiplying its both sides by $\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}$.

There is my attempt
$$
S_n=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\geq\sqrt{n}
$$
$$
S_n\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}\geq\sqrt{n+1}
$$
Here, it is necessary to prove that $S_n+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\geq S_n\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}$.
$$
S_n+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}?S_n\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}?S_n\left(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}-1\right)
$$
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}?S_n\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1-\sqrt{n^2+n}}?S_n
$$
All of transformations applied to the inequality above are equivalent such that the sign "?" of inequality did not change.

I have no idea how to prove that $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1-\sqrt{n^2+n}}\geq S_n$.

Comment: Very good idea.  You have nailed down the two main weapons in such an induction setting, namely consideration of both $(a_{n+1} - a_n)$ and $\displaystyle \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$.  For this particular problem, my immediate instinct is that the 2nd approach is *much* *uglier* than the 1st approach, so I wouldn't go near the 2nd approach unless I was convinced that the 1st approach just can't work.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. It is clear that 1st approach is better than 2nd so I have already used it. I asked this question because I have problem using the 2nd approach to the inequality.

Comment: I suggest that you abandon the idea of using the 2nd approach.

Comment: Why? I thought it would be a nice exercise to take a different path.

Comment: Common, in my experience with such problems, that the problem composer intends that only one path be taken, and that the other path is very ugly, with no educational value.  I am speaking from experience re these kinds of problems.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, @PrasunBiswas. But $S_{n+1}=S_n+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$

Comment: @Alakey: Ah yes, I wondered why I didn't have to do $\sqrt{n}+\frac 1{\sqrt{n+1}}\ge\sqrt{n+1}$ or the like there. Here's the corrected version: \begin{align}S_{n+1}&=S_n+\frac 1{\sqrt{n+1}}\\&=\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+1}}\left[S_n\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt n}+\frac 1{\sqrt n}\right]\\&\ge\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+1}}\left[\sqrt{n+1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right]\\&=\sqrt n+\frac 1{\sqrt{n+1}}\\&=\frac{\sqrt n\sqrt{n+1}+1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\ge\frac{\sqrt n\sqrt n+1}{\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n+1}}=\sqrt{n+1}\end{align}

Comment: The point is, it is just a roundabout way of doing the same as you do with the first approach (which is far more simpler to write and work out).

Comment: 0th approach: You have $n$ terms on the left-hand side, each of which is $\ge 1/\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the proof of 'Here, it is necessary...' but any way a proof by induction is one that would be almost similar in any case, a direct proof may be:
Divide the two members by $\sqrt{n}$ then we prove $$\dfrac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\ge 1$$ or $$\dfrac{S_{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}}+\dfrac{1}{n}\ge 1$$ but  the first term verifies easily $$\dfrac{S_{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}}> \dfrac{n-1}{n}$$ which implies the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

The part $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1-\sqrt{n^2+n}}>S_n$ requires induction.

Consider the inequality above when n=1:
$$
\frac{1}{2-\sqrt{2}}>1
$$
$$
-1>-\sqrt{2} - true
$$
Let the inequality be correct for some value n. Then add $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ to both sides:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1-\sqrt{n^2+n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{n(n+1)}+(n+1)-\sqrt{n(n+1)}}{(n+1)(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}>S_{n+1}
$$
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n+2-\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}
$$
$$
n+1-\sqrt{n(n+1)}>n+2-\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}
$$
$$
\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}-1>\sqrt{n(n+1)}
$$
$$
(n+1)(n+2)-2\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}+1>n(n+1)
$$
$$
(n+1)(n+2-n)+1>2\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}
$$
$$
2(n+1)+1>2\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}
$$
$$
4(n+1)^2+4(n+1)+1>4(n+1)(n+2)
$$
$$
n+2+\frac{1}{4(n+1)}>n+2 - true
$$